# how to set original size of image when using collageplus plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am displaying images within a div using **jQuery collagePlus Plugin v0.3.3**.Its working fine but my problem is, the images size will increase and broke the orginal effect of images.when i upload images its display like below,

[image]

when i use code,

```
$('#clickAlignButton').click(function(){
     $('.divimages').collagePlus();
    });
```

that images display like below,

[image]

I want to display all uploaded images horizontly align with its orginal effect.

I tried to change code inside the collageplus.js like,

```
  $img.width(fw);
                if( !$obj.is("img") ){
                   // $obj.width(fw + obj[i][3]);
                    $obj.width("50px");
                }


                /*
                 *
                 * Set the height of the image
                 * if the resized element is not an image, we apply it to the child image also
                 *
                 */
                $img.height(fh);
                if( !$obj.is("img") ){
                    //$obj.height(fh + obj[i][4]);
                    $obj.height("70px");
                }
```

but no use!.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/46psK/944/

How to fix this?

Comment: show your markup, if you don't mind. Better yet, do a codepen.io or a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Todd I understand but how to add collageplus plugins into jsfiddle or codepen.io bec if add that plugin only i can show my problem!

Comment: I don't understand. If you add your plugin and code into jsfiddle and share the link, why wouldn't that work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/edlea/uZv3n/

Comment: oh ok now i understood.wait, i do and share link

Comment: @Todd check my demo here http://jsfiddle.net/46psK/944/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65334/discussion-between-manivasagam-and-todd).